# Why are signals broadened in polarography?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry

In the attached polarogram from Heyvrovsky's 1959 Nobel lecture, transitions from one plateau to the next are smoothened out rather than sharp and abrupt. Why is that?

I understand that currents were small in this experiment, so metal ion concentrations should not change significantly.

I would have expected the current to jump from one level to the next as soon as the necessary voltage is reached. What broadens these transitions?

https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/chemistry/laureates/1959/heyrovsky-lecture.pdf

[image: Heyvrovsky polarogram]

Comment: Related question: Polarography is less popular nowadays than it used to be, but can anyone point me to contemporary applications / results that I could show my students?

Comment: Before actually reaching the reduction potential, reduction of the metal ions happens only in very tiny amounts, but eventually becomes measurable as the equilibrium constant approaches 1 from below, (e.g. 0.001 → 0.01 → 0.1 → 0.5 → ...). I discuss something similar in [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7440/1499).